# How do I "stretch" (interpolate) an array but keep its underlying data intact?

Tags: matlab

I have two splines that I've generated with (a bit of modification of) `getcurve()` which represent an `XY` and `XZ` of a trajectory. I would like to combine the two splines together to generate a 3d plot, via `plot3()`. I modified `getcurve()` to output the `XData` and `YData` of the line drawn on the plot.

Since the splines are graphically generated, the number of elements won't necessarily be the same between `XY` and `XZ`. Suppose `length(XY)>length(XZ)`. I'm trying to create a new vector `XZ_2` that has the same length as `XY` and has the same x-values as `XY`.

My first idea was to interpolate as follows:

```
XZ_2(:,2) = interp1(XZ(:,1), XZ(:,2), XY(:,1))
```

but I get an error:

```
Error using griddedInterpolant
The grid vectors are not strictly monotonic increasing.
Error in interp1 (line 191)
    F = griddedInterpolant(X,V,method);
```

The spline `XZ` looks like this:

[image: XZ spline]

I don't understand why I can't interpolate given this spline. It doesn't look like anything special. You can rebuild this spline yourself by doing the following (you'll need the Curve Fitting Toolbox):

```
>> xz = [0.0288    0.0518    0.1071    0.1763    0.2707    0.3583    0.4988    0.5864    0.7339    0.8191    0.9182    0.9781
         1.8070    1.3626    0.9766    0.4152   -0.0643   -0.3684   -0.9181   -1.1637   -1.4795   -1.6667   -1.8070   -1.9474];
>> fnplt(cscvn(xz));
```

Is there a way to "resize" `XZ` to use the same x-values as `XY`? I realize that some information about `XZ` will be lost when I do this, but that's okay.

Comment: Couldn't you skip this bit and go straight to 3D using interp2?

Comment: Could I? I thought `interp2` let you interpolate on a surface. I'm not quite seeing how I would use it to generate a curve rather than a surface.

Comment: Oh sorry I though you wanted to combine the 2 curves to make a surface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it says that in `interp1(x, y, xi);`, the `x` and `xi` must be monotonic increasing, i.e. sorted.

Comment: Does it have to be increasing? I thought it had to be monotonic one way or the other.  Although I suppose the OP's plot answers my question for me.

Comment: `x` and `xi` must be increasing, `y` is irrelevant. Consider {x,y} as a time series.

Comment: I found a SINGLE repeated value. Ugh! Using [Consolidator](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8354) from the MATLAB File Exchange helped out with this issue.